# Podofo build errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdf, cmake, podofo

I want to build solution for Visual Studio.
As i know, minumum for it is cmake, zlib, jpeg and freetype.
I build freetype(debug and relise).
Downloaded compiled zlib dll.
(For Visual Studio you will need to build libjpeg with your version of Visual Studio. Download the libjpeg sources from [here](http://www.ijg.org/) and unpack them into a working directory. I'll assume you've used C:\Developer\jpeg. Once the sources are unpacked, start a visual studio command prompt and cd into c:\developer\jpeg then run copy jconfig.vc jconfig.h then nmake /f makefile.vc /a)
 Jpeg done, or i need something more to do with it?

Then i make cmd file:

```
del cmakecache.txt
set FTDIR=C:\dev\freetype-2.4.5
set FTLIBDIR=C:\dev\freetype-2.4.5\objs\win32\vc2010
set JPEGDIR=C:\dev\jpeg
set ZLIBDIR=C:\developer\zlib128-dll
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" c:\dev\podofo-0.9.2\  -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="%FTDIR%\include;%JPEGDIR%\include;%JPEGDIR%;%ZLIBDIR%\include" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="%FTLIBDIR%;%FTDIR%\lib;%JPEGDIR%;%JPEGDIR%;%ZLIBDIR%\lib" -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG=freetype245MT_D -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE=freetype245MT -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```

Then i can see that:

```
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - not found
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h
-- Looking for arpa/inet.h - not found
-- Looking for winsock2.h
-- Looking for winsock2.h - found
-- Looking for mem.h
-- Looking for mem.h - not found
-- Looking for ctype.h
-- Looking for ctype.h - found
```

Maybe problem is this or maybe in jpeg lib.

Comment: You need to make the include path find the standard headers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nmake directly, I'd recommend you use cmake-gui for building PoDoFo. Don't write your own build.cmd as this doesn't work in most cases. **Note** : The method described below uses your method, don't follow it. Use cmake-gui (If you don't know how exactly cmake or nmake works).

Well I will recommend you go to this site and find the references:
[Building static podofo with MSVS 2012](http://bugbeebox.com/2012/12/30/building-static-podofo-0-9-1-with-msvc-2012/)
Well I guess this should work for Visual Studio 2010. Remember :

1. **Building the prerequisite libraries** - This site has also links about how to go on building these libraries. However, I assume you have already built them. However I would recommend building them again according to this tutorial.
2. **Instructions** : Do as he says. Don't miss any options regarding preprocessor definitions, runtime libraries and all the parameters same. If you miss anything or do something wrong that will force you to restart from where you started.
3. **Errors :** I myself experienced many errors while following the same procedure and this site provides no explanation. Common errors include:

   - Unresolved externals (either with msvcrt.lib or libcmt.lib). In that case, just go to **Linker>Input>Ignore specific libraries** and name that library there to just ignore it.
   - There will be random errors sometimes. I would suggest looking up Stack Overflow itself or MSDN or Google, because after starting off with >2500 errors I was finally able to build a static library.
4. **Last Resort**: If everything fails, just contact me (if you are still interested!).